# Regex replace priority

Tags: regex, replace, preg-replace, regex-greedy

Let's say I have the string:

```
we have apple, coconut and grapes.
```

If I use the regex:

```
^.*\b((apple)|(coconut)|(grape)|(grapes)).*$
```

to replace with

```
|$2|$3|$4|$5
```

It will output `|||grape|` as it goes greedy by `.*` and then matches from right to left.

How can I prioritise the replace to first try out the **first pattern group** (in my example '(apple)') for the whole string before trying group 2 or 3 and so on, sort of like it happens for just one character match when I replace order between `grapes` and `grape` changing the output to `|||grapes|`.

I can do this using multiple replaces but I fear the overhead of calling regex from mssql multiple times might result in too much overhead.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? What is your end expected result? Is it `|apple|||`?

Comment: Is this what you want: http://regex101.com/r/yK8jF8 ?

Comment: @Jerry yes, apple is what I want, order of replace should be  apple, coconut, grape, grapes.
@Passerby no, it just changes the order from left to right if I put `^.*?\b((coconut)|(apple)|(grape)|(grapes)).*?$` it still outputs `|apple|||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this maybe?

```
^((?:.*?(\bapple\b))|(?:.*?(\bcoconut\b))|(?:.*?(\bgrape\b))|(?:.*?(\bgrapes\b))).*$
```

`apple` has priority, then `coconut`, afterwards `grape`, and last `grapes`.

Comment: Seems that this is the most straightforward way to do it, I'll test to see if performance-wise is the best option.

Comment: works great, it's exactly what I want, I was unsure at first about `?:`, thought it would be some complicated regex look-around, but I know now that it's just the symbol for non-capturing Groups.

Comment: @clickstefan Awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives in a regex alternation are tried from left to right, so you either need to put the longer alternatives first

```
^.*\b((apple)|(coconut)|(grapes)|(grape)).*$
```

or make sure that only entire word matches by using another word boundary:

```
^.*\b((apple)|(coconut)|(grape)|(grapes))\b.*$
```

Comment: sorry for the confusing question, grape and grapes are there just for example, what I really want is to match `(apple)` or wathever is the first group first and after try to match the other groups.

Also sorting by length wouldn't have any effect in my case, also I've given a simplified version of my regex, I have other `|` in the groups.

Comment: the actual regex is something like `^.*\b((apple|pears|plums|peaches)|(coconut|banana)|(grape[a-z]+|[a-z]+berry))\b.*$`.

Comment: OK, so that's a totally different question. However, I still don't see the problem. The first group is attempted first, then the second, then the third. There is no overlap in your potential matches. Oversimplifying the problem is unlikely to get you a valid solution.

Comment: if you replace `(apple)` with `(coconut)` then `(coconut)` should match but that doesn't happen, `apple` is still matched.

Comment: see the comments for @Passerby above

Comment: @clickstefan: Ahhhh, now I get it. You want the capturing groups to match in their own order, regardless of the order of the matching texts...then Jerry's solution is probably the best way to go. It only allows for one single match, though. If that's OK, great.